# Making a dice in ruby language

Tags: ruby, direction, dice

Im coding a dice in ruby in which when i rolled it, it would either come up north south east or west.

what im having trouble with is when i roll it  how do i tell it to return to me one of these directions?

any help would be great.

Comment: should i just put the four directions in an array and get it return me a random index in the array ?

Comment: or should i retun a random number between one and 16 and assign 4 values to each direction . eg if it returns 1-4 its east         
                                    returns 5-8 its west
                                    returns 9-12 its north
                                    returns 13-16 its south?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.sample`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000285):

```
[ 'north', 'south', 'east', 'west' ].sample
```

Comment: `Array#choice` was removed in 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't get much easier than `%w(north south east west).sample` (that's 1.9 method btw). Another thing that works in 1.8 and 1.9 is `%w(north south east west)[rand(4)]`.

Comment: Glad to help. If this was the answer you were looking for, please accept and/or upvote it.